# Options/properties for apps not showing on data flow server or shell

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

When attempting to create a new stream in the data flow server or shell there are no options/properties being shown. Similar output below from shell. I've also include the logs from the SCDF server - https://gist.githubusercontent.com/pbarriscale/d88802c7b96316636d3db441f3a7633c/raw/00f338bee957aa26c4ac621d95a680f67d24f982/scdf.log

I can deploy and launch a simple timestamp task app which runs successfully.

I've following the instructions as outlined at http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-kubernetes/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#_getting_started

Used Bulk Import Applications on the SCDF UI and selected Docker based Stream Applications with Kafka Binder and Docker based Task Applications.

My system info.

CoreOS stable (1185.3.0)
Docker 1.11.2
Kubernetes v1.3.7
3 Kubernetes nodes

Thanks

```
dataflow:>app info --id source:twitterstream
Information about source application 'twitterstream':
Resource URI: docker:springcloudstream/twitterstream-source-kafka:1.0.2.RELEASE
╔══════════════════════════════╤══════════════════════════════╤══════════════════════════════╤══════════════════════════════╗
║         Option Name          │         Description          │           Default            │             Type             ║
╚══════════════════════════════╧══════════════════════════════╧══════════════════════════════╧══════════════════════════════╝
```

Answer (score 0):

The application metadata retrieval for `docker` based applications is yet to be supported. This is being tracked [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/issues/888)

Comment: Ok thanks. So do docker based apps, specifically streams work on any platform? I had a subsequent issue where deploying the example ticktock stream (time | log) did not work on the same environment either. I was guessing it was because of this issue I reported. The time and log apps deploy successfully to the kubernetes cluster, startup and then continually restart. I can provide additional info including logs if required.

Comment: @Paul: There's a gap with Docker artifacts. We are still exploring options to track of "app properties" for artifacts bundled as Docker images. There's plan to cache just the app metadata to support content-assist, shell and UI requirements. Though you aren't able to see the app metadata, the streams when deployed with them should work in k8s/mesos. If you're seeing issues with it (_continual restarts_), please open a issue [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-kubernetes/issues) with the logs.